# Nested JSON with variable keys to TSV using jq

Tags: json, csv, key, export-to-csv, jq

I have the following nested JSON file `labs.json` with variable keywords (`lab001`, `lab002`, etc.) which I would like to convert into a TSV using `jq`:

```
{
  "lab001": {
    "tags": {
      "T1": [],
      "T2": ["k26","e23"],
      "T3": ["s92"]
    },
    "code": "8231"
  },
  "lab002": {
    "tags": {
      "T1": ["t32","y55"],
      "T2": ["q78"],
      "T3": ["b24"]
    },
    "code": "9112"
  }
}
```

The resulting table should look like:

| ID | T1 | T2 | T3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lab001 |  | k26,e23 | s92 |
| lab002 | t32,y55 | q78 | b24 |

Currently I am using a rather pedestrian approach by pasting two calls of `jq` and doing some cleanup with `tr`:

```
paste <(jq -r 'keys_unsorted | @csv' labs.json | tr ',' '\n') <(jq -r '.[].tags | map(tostring) | @tsv' labs.json) | tr -d '[]"'
```

Is there any more elegant way to get this done purely with `jq`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join elements of each tag by commas, put resulting strings into an array with the lab ID as the first element, and pipe it to the `@tsv` filter like so:

```
keys_unsorted[] as $id | [$id, (.[$id].tags[] | join(","))] | @tsv
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/mdJ642Qmtf)</sup>